# Show that $H(U)$ the space of holomorphic functions on $U$ is not normable.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show the following result:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set. Show that the vector space $H(U)=\{f:U \to \mathbb{C} \; \text{analytic}\}$ is not normable.

I know that $H(U)$ is a Frechet space. If we take $A_{k}:=\{z \in U\ : |z| \leq k \; , \; \text{dist}(\partial U,z) \geq \frac{1}{k} \}$ and $p_{k}(f)=\sup_{z \in A_{k}}|f(z)|$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$\cup_{k}A_{k}=U$ and metric

$$d(f,g)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}} \frac{p_{k}(f-g)}{1+p_{k}(f-g)}.$$

I'm not sure how to work with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to understand this (if the required topology is uniform convergence on compacts) is to consider the "derivative" operator $d:H(U) \rightarrow H(U)$. Suppose $H(U)$ is normable. Then $d$ is sequentially continuous so has a bounded operator norm.
In particular, its eigenvalues are bounded.

But, for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $d$ with eigenvector $z \in U \longmapsto e^{\lambda z}$, so we get a contradiction.

Comment: NIce argument.  And I suppose you argue that the derivative operator is continuous using Cauchy's integral formula, correct?

Comment: So a sufficient condition for a Frechet space to be NOT normable is the existence of a continuous linear operator with unbounded spectrum.  I wonder if  this is necessary as well.

Comment: @Ruy: yes to your first comment. I really don’t know if it’s necessary though (but I would incline to say ‘no’ in general).

Answer (score 3):

Supposing  by contradiction that $H(U)$ is normable via some norm $\|{\cdot}\|$, observe that  the set
$$
  B:= \{f\in H(U): \|f\|<1\}
  $$
is open, so there exists some $\varepsilon >0$, such that
$$
  \Omega :=\{f\in H(U): d(f, 0)≤\varepsilon \}\subseteq  B.
  $$

Notice moreover  that, for every $z$ in $U$, the point evaluation
$$
  \delta _z: f\in  H(U) \mapsto  f(z)\in  \mathbb C
  $$
is a continuous linear functional.  So,
given any $f$ in $\Omega $, and any $z\in U$, we  have that
$$
  |f(z)|  \leq  \|\delta _z\| \|f\| \leq   \|\delta _z\|.
  \tag 1
  $$

This is the first indication that something is wrong, since the functions in $H(U)$ are not necessarily bounded.
Choose $n$ such that $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k}≤\varepsilon /2$ and notice that, since
$$
  A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_n
  $$
we have that
$p_1\leq p_2\leq \cdots \leq p_n$, whence for every $f$ in $H(U)$ we have
$$
  d(f,0) =
  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k} \frac{p_k(f)}{1+p_k(f)} \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k} \frac{p_k(f)}{1+p_k(f)} +   \sum_{k=n+1}^n\frac1{2^k} \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}\Big) \frac{p_n(f)}{1+p_n(f)} +  \frac\varepsilon 2 \leq
  \frac{p_n(f)}{1+p_n(f)} +  \frac\varepsilon 2.
  $$
Chosing $\delta >0$ such that
$$
  0\leq x\leq \delta \Rightarrow \frac{x}{1+x}\leq \varepsilon /2,
  $$
we then deduce that
$$
  p_n(f)\leq \delta  \Rightarrow d(f,0)\leq \varepsilon.
  $$

Summing up  we have by (1) that
$$
  \sup_{z\in A_n}|f(z)| \leq  \delta  \Rightarrow  f\in \Omega   \Rightarrow  |f(z)| \leq  \|\delta _z\|,\quad \forall z\in  U.
  \tag 2
  $$

Picking any point $z_0$ in $U\setminus A_n$ it is now easy to choose some holomorphic function $f$ on $U$ that is
bounded by $\delta $ on $A_n$, and takes on an arbitrarily large value on $z_0$, e.g. bigger that $ \|\delta _{z_0}\|$, thus
contradicting (2).

Comment: Since this post is getting increasingly competitive $\ddot\smile$ let me do a little publicity by pointing out that the above proof works not only for $H(U)$, but also for $\mathscr C^\infty(U)$, where $U$ is any open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and $d$ is the *ipsis litteris* generalization of the metric proposed by the OP.  As observed by @Matsmir, the argument based on Montel's Theorem works on $\mathscr C^\infty(U)$, but with a different topology, namely uniform convergence of all derivatives on compact sets.

Comment: Hi! Your $A_i$'s are compact sets right? And could you propose one concrete holmorphic function that serves as the final contradiction?

Comment: @Sarah, Yes,  the $A_i$ are compact.  As for your second question, since $z₀$ is not in $A_n$, then either $|z_0|>n$, or $\text{dist}(\partial U,z_0)<1/n$.  Assuming the latter,
pick $w$ in $\partial U$ with $|w-z₀|<1/n$, and notice that the function
  $$
  f(z) = \frac 1{w-z}, \quad (z∈U),
  $$
  lies in $H(U)$, that $|f(z₀)|>n$, and that $|f(z)|≤n$, for $z∈ A_n$.  Choosing a suitable positive real number  $α$, and a suitable positive integer $m$, the function
  $$
  g(z) = (αf(z))^m
  $$
  will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: This takes care of the case "$\text{dist}(\partial U,z_0)<1/n$", and I bet you are able
to do the case "$|z_0|>n$" by yourself!

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to prove this by using Montel theorem. It states that if $f_n \in H(U)$ is a bounded sequence (i.e. it is bounded by means of seminorms $p_k$) then there is a convergent subsequence $f_{n_m}$. Thus, if $H(U)$ is normable then its unit ball is a bounded subset and, therefore, by Montel theorem it is compact. Now we observe that a normable space with compact unit ball is finite dimensional. Therefore, $H(U)$ is not normable.

There is an abstract notion of Montel space: a barrelled locally convex space in which all closed bounded subsets are compact. $H(U)$ is a Montel space (a simple corollary of Montel theorem). The foregoing argument shows that a normable space is Montel iff it is finite dimensional. By the same reason the space $C^\infty(U)$ is not normable (with the topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives on compact subsets of $U$).

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify how boundedness on the norm implies that of the seminorms?

Comment: @Sarah Boundedness is a topological notion in a TVS (defined as the absorbtion by neighborhoods of zero). If the topology is normable then boundedness can be described as boundedness with respect to that norm